# Почему размер класса (this) и размер экземпляра класса (в функции main) отличаются?

Tags: visual-studio, указатели, c++11, windows-7, x86-64

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class CSimple
{
public:
    void show()
    {
        cout << "size: " << __FUNCTION__ << " " << sizeof(this) << endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    CSimple obj;
    obj.show();
    cout << "size: " __FUNCTION__ << " " << sizeof(CSimple) << endl;
    //cout << "size: " __FUNCTION__ << " " << sizeof(obj) << endl; // такой же результат 
}
```

/----------x64---------/

size: CSimple::show 8

size: main 1

/----------x86---------/

size: CSimple::show 4

size: main 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` - это обычный *указатель*, соответственно, его размер - 8 или 4 байта в 64- и 32-разрадных системах соответственно.

Пустой класс имеет размер 1 байт. Так заведено по ряду причин. Простейшая - ну, например, чтоб можно было иметь массив таких объектов :)

Так что все логично...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Действительно, упустил очевидное. Если написать так, все проясняется!

    cout << "size: " << __FUNCTION__ << " " << sizeof(*this) << endl;